# Pinning 2D array of enum

Tags: arrays, enums, c++-cli, pinning

I have a specific issue passing `enum` from managed to unmanaged layer - basically with pinning the `enum` array.

My use case is I have a 1D array of reference type (T) which contains a buffer (2D array of `enum` backed by byte).

buffer (2D Array of `enum` backed by byte) is allocated on managed heap and I want to pass that buffer to unmanaged layer - to fill it with some values. At the same time I want to make sure that Garbage Collector (GC) does not move the buffer around when unmanaged method is filling in data to the buffer. In order to do that I have to pin the buffer. The language that I am using for managed code is `C++/CLI,` which provides 2 way of pinning the buffer

- `cli::pin_ptr`
- `GCHandle`

For some reason I cannot pin buffer using `GCHandle` - I get `ArgumentException` - may be because `enum` is non-blittable type.

I can pin buffer with `cli::pin_ptr` though, however problem with `cli::pin_ptr` is that because array of reference type in discussion, (which contains buffer - 2D array of enum backed by byte), can be variable length, I will need more than one `pin_ptr` (array of `pin_ptr`) to pin buffer in each reference type instance. And I cannot have array of `cli::pin_ptr`.

This is blocking me for implementing specific feature in .NET Application - as I cannot pin the 2D array of `enum` correctly.

Comment: Is this correct for your data structure? `ref class MyClass{ array<MyEnum, 2>^ innerTwoDimArray; };`, `array<MyClass^>^ outerArray;`?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pin the wrong thing. As David implies, please post your data structure and say what part *exactly* you are trying to pin.